# org-mode: Open parent directory of linked file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a function in org-mode to open the parent directory of a linked file instead of the file itself?

Background: Having links to files under version control (subversion), I want to update the file before opening it.

Comment: Update the file in what way? It's not clear to me why you want to open the directory. Regardless, have you tried enabling version-control in emacs? See [Version Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html#Version-Control).

Comment: “SVN Update” means getting the current version of the file from the repository.I am using an external file manager to open directory links (by configuring org-file-apps) and I am calling the “SVN Update“ manually there. Using version control within Emacs is not the solution I am looking for at the moment. (Perhaps I shouldn`t have mentioned the background ^^)

Answer (score 0):

The main question I have is: when you click on the link, do you *always* expect to go to the containing directory? If so, why not change the link
to point to the directory, instead of pointing to the file?

If you sometimes want to go to the directory and sometimes to the file,
then you *might* (no guarantees) be able to do it by [defining your own link type](http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html#Adding-hyperlink-types) (but note that `org-add-link-type` was declared obsolete in v9.0 and you are supposed to use `org-link-set-parameters` instead - the manual needs updating). You'll need to program the criteria (or perhaps supply an argument somehow) for when you want to visit the directory and when you want to visit the file.